# Reading XML Node in C#

Tags: c#, xml

I have a .xml that is formatted like this:

```
<!--List of Locations-->
<Locations>
    <Location Name="House">
        <XCoord>0</XCoord>
        <YCoord>0</YCoord>
        <ZCoord>0</ZCoord>
    </Location>
</Locations>
```

I want to be able to read the "House" part of it and store it as a string, can anybody help?

Comment: What have you tried? I'd suggest [`XDocument`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.xml.linq.xdocument(v=vs.110).aspx) as a starting point.

Comment: I recommend searching about Linq to Xml.

Comment: As a side note it's usually best for you to put your attempted code up for others to work with rather than just asking for an answer.

Comment: Please don't just ask us to solve the problem for you. Show us how _you_ tried to solve the problem yourself, then show us _exactly_ what the result was, and tell us why you feel it didn't work. See "[What Have You Tried?](http://whathaveyoutried.com/)" for an excellent article that you _really need to read_.

Comment: Also, what do you mean "the House part of it"? Just the word "House", or the entire `<Location>` element which has `Name="House"`?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Below is using XDocument and will grab all the location element below the root element locations and make an IEnumerable with all the names.

```
var xml = "<Locations><Location Name=\"House\"><XCoord>0</XCoord><YCoord>0</YCoord><ZCoord>0</ZCoord></Location></Locations>";

var xDoc = XDocument.Parse(xml);

var attributes = 
        xDoc.Root //Locations
            .Elements() //Each individual Location
            .Select(element => element.Attribute("Name").Value); //Grab all the name attribute values
```

`attributes` variable is an `IEnumerable<string>` of the name values.

Answer (score 0):

Parse the xml with XDocument

```
XDocument doc = XDocument.Parse(xml);
```

Select the house elements

```
IEnumerable<string> nameValues =
            from el in doc.Root.Elements()
            where el.Attribute("Name") != null
            select el.Attribute("Name").Value;
```

Comment: You can use Linq projections and convert to a string during the Linq Query.

Comment: I have edited the answer according to Cubicle.Jockeys suggestion.

Comment: Well that's not what I meant and your code won't work. I will edit your answer take a peek in a second.

Comment: Even though I the question stats how I am pretty sure they want to be able to read all of the Location Name attributes not just the ones restricted to matching House, other wise they would just get a long string of nothing but House house house house house and seems pretty pointless.

Comment: I misunderstood the question due to its vagueness